# How to use a range for columns instead of names for pmax / pmin

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to use a range of columns in pmax/pmin instead of typing names of all columns.

```
#sample data
foo <- data.frame(sapply(letters, function(x) x = sample(1:10,5)))

#this works
bar <- foo %>% 
    mutate(maxcol = pmax(a,b,c))

# this does not work
bar <- foo %>% 
    mutate(maxcol = pmax(a:z))
```

Ultimately I also want something like this

```
bar <- foo %>% 
    mutate_at(a:z = pmax(a:z))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an option that does *one* function-call on *all rows, all columns* at once.

```r
foo %>%
  mutate(maxcol = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = a:e)))
#    a  b c d e  f g  h  i j  k l m  n  o p q  r  s t u  v w  x  y z maxcol
# 1  1  4 9 2 4  4 1 10  2 3 10 4 7  1 10 9 8  2  8 9 5  1 9  1 10 9      9
# 2  5  2 5 3 5  2 8  8  5 8  2 3 6 10  9 3 5  8  7 4 6  9 8  5  8 3      5
# 3 10  9 6 1 7 10 6  4  4 7  6 6 2  7  5 5 4  1 10 7 3 10 5 10  1 7     10
# 4  8  1 4 8 9  3 3  9 10 1  8 5 8  4  4 8 6 10  5 2 9  5 7  7  3 1      9
# 5  2 10 2 9 8  9 9  6  7 5  9 2 5  5  7 4 2  5  4 8 4  6 6  2  9 6     10
```

You can select some or all of the columns using the colon notation, even arbitrary columns:

```r
foo %>%
  mutate(maxcol = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = c(a:e,g))))
#    a  b c d e  f g  h  i j  k l m  n  o p q  r  s t u  v w  x  y z maxcol
# 1  1  4 9 2 4  4 1 10  2 3 10 4 7  1 10 9 8  2  8 9 5  1 9  1 10 9      9
# 2  5  2 5 3 5  2 8  8  5 8  2 3 6 10  9 3 5  8  7 4 6  9 8  5  8 3      8
# 3 10  9 6 1 7 10 6  4  4 7  6 6 2  7  5 5 4  1 10 7 3 10 5 10  1 7     10
# 4  8  1 4 8 9  3 3  9 10 1  8 5 8  4  4 8 6 10  5 2 9  5 7  7  3 1      9
# 5  2 10 2 9 8  9 9  6  7 5  9 2 5  5  7 4 2  5  4 8 4  6 6  2  9 6     10
```

The reason this should be preferred over the other answers (which are generally using allegedly idiomatic methods) is because:

- in Dom's answer, the `max` function is called once for each row of the frame; R's vectorized ops are not being used, this is inefficient and should be avoided if possible;
- in akrun's answer, `pmax` is being called once for each column of the frame, which in this case might sound worse but actually closer to the best one can do. My answer is closest to akrun's in that we are `select`ing data within the `mutate`.

If you'd prefer to use `dplyr::select` over `base::subset`, it needs to be broken out as

```r
foo %>%
  mutate(maxcol = select(., a:e, g) %>% do.call(pmax, .))
```

I think this is demonstrated a little better with benchmarks. Using the provided 5x26 frame, we see a clear improvement:

```r
set.seed(42)
foo <- data.frame(sapply(letters, function(x) x = sample(1:10,5)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Dom = {
    foo %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      summarise(max= max(c_across(a:z)))
  },
  akr = {
    foo %>%
       mutate(maxcol = reduce(select(., a:z), pmax))
  },
  r2 = {
    foo %>%
      mutate(maxcol = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = a:z)))
  }
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr    min      lq    mean  median      uq     max neval
#   Dom 6.6561 7.15260 7.61574 7.38345 7.90375 11.0387   100
#   akr 4.2849 4.69920 4.96278 4.86110 5.18130  7.0908   100
#    r2 2.3290 2.49285 2.68671 2.59180 2.78960  4.7086   100
```

Let's try with a slightly larger 5000x26:

```r
set.seed(42)
foo <- data.frame(sapply(letters, function(x) x = sample(1:10,5000,replace=TRUE)))
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  Dom = {
    foo %>% 
      rowwise() %>% 
      summarise(max= max(c_across(a:z)))
  },
  akr = {
    foo %>%
       mutate(maxcol = reduce(select(., a:z), pmax))
  },
  r2 = {
    foo %>%
      mutate(maxcol = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = a:z)))
  }
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#  expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
#   Dom 515.6437 563.6060 763.97348 811.45815 883.00115 1775.2366   100
#   akr   4.6660   5.1619  11.92847   5.74050   6.50625  293.7444   100
#    r2   2.9253   3.4371   4.24548   3.71845   4.27380   14.0958   100
```

This last one definitely shows a consequence of using `rowwise`. The relative performance between akrun's answer and this one is almost identical to 5 rows, reinforcing the premise that column-wise is better than row-wise (and all-at-once is faster than both).

(This can also be done with `purrr::invoke`, if truly desired, though it does not speed it up:

```r
library(purrr)
foo %>%
  mutate(maxcol = invoke(pmax, subset(., select = a:z)))

### microbenchmark(...)
# Unit: milliseconds
#     expr    min      lq    mean  median      uq      max neval
#      Dom 7.8292 8.40275 9.02813 8.97345 9.38500  12.4368   100
#      akr 4.9622 5.28855 8.78909 5.60090 6.11790 309.2607   100
#   r2base 2.5521 2.74635 3.01949 2.90415 3.21060   4.6512   100
#  r2purrr 2.5063 2.77510 3.11206 2.93415 3.33015   5.2403   100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `rowwise` and `c_across` (depends on `dplyr` >= 1.0.0):

```
library(dplyr)

foo %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  summarise(max= max(c_across(a:z)))

`summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 5 x 1
    max
  <int>
1    10
2    10
3    10
4    10
5    10
```

Comment: does rowwise stay like group_by meaning, would the next operation be done rowwise? How to remove rowwise if it stays ?

Comment: It stays grouped by row if used with `mutate`. Just add an `%>% ungroup()` to get rid of the row-wise grouping.

Comment: While this answer is [canonical to `dplyr::c_across`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html), I find it interesting that the docs suggest `rowwise` as the first way to do this, despite its poor scaling performance when compared to column-wise (akrun's) or all-at-once vectorized (my answer).

Comment: @r2evans what docs ? can you please add a ref to that ?

Comment: *"the docs"* referred to the "canonical" link seven words prior. Specifically, it says that `c_across` was designed to use with `rowwise`, and the last chunk of code in the "Examples" section uses `%>% rowwise() %>% mutate(... sum(c_across(...)))`.

Answer (score 2):

We `select` the columns from a to z (`select(., a:z)`), and `reduce` it to a single vector/column after applying the `pmax` on each corresponding row of the columns

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
foo %>%
     mutate(maxcol = reduce(select(., a:z), pmax))
```

Or another option is to splice (`!!!` which forces-splice a list of objects.

```
foo %>% 
     mutate(maxcol = pmax(!!! .))
```

We can also use `pmax` with `do.call` in `base R`

```
foo$maxcol <- do.call(pmax, foo)
```

Comment: Can you please add some information on what `reduce` does and what `!!!` is ? Thanks!

Comment: @AshishSinghal added some more info.  The `reduce` is similar in its action to `do.call` from `base R`, `do.call(pmax, foo)` (for certain functions)

Comment: Not correct. `purrr::reduce` is similar to base R's `Reduce`, whereas `purrr::invoke` is similar to R's `do.call`. The biggest difference is that `invoke`/`do.call` make *one* call to the function, and `reduce`/`Reduce` make `n-1` calls, where `n` is the number of arguments in its list; `a:z` is 26 columns, so `pmax` is called 25 times.

Comment: Your use of `do.call(pmax, foo)` works for all columns but doesn't work as well within a dplyr pipe on a subset of columns, which is what I inferred from the OP's use of `pmax(a,b,c)`. Perhaps I mis-interpreted the desire for column-subsetting.

Comment: @r2evans I was thinking about the OP's `# this does not work` with `a:z` with full columns.  Anyway, it's okay.  You have some clear explanations with benchmarks.  Good to know the efficiencies.  Thanks

Comment: I needed to subset some columns ` mutate(maxcol = do.call(pmax, subset(., select = a:e)))` does what I want. which I think is similar to `foo$maxcol <- do.call(pmax, foo)`.